# Get syntax highlighting in documentation on hover. Android Studio (flutter/dart)

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am trying to get syntax highlighting when hovering a variable (documentation window). It just shows gray and I think this shows with highlighting with other languages in Android Studio.

Example:

[image: How this is being showned]

Thanks in advance!